# AEM6 :: Sling Servlet Not found 404

Tags: aem, siteminder

I have created a login component that has a form and it has a POST action to a URL pointing to the siteminder URL https://test1-myuhc.uhc.com/siteminderagent/forms/login-aa.fcc

```
<input type="hidden" name="target" value="/bin/uhc/myuhcauthenticationhandler">
```

Inside the form the 'target' hidden field is where the siteminder forwards the request. The target that I have set here points to a Sling Servlet. The Servlet upon some kind of authentication does redirection to appropriate pages in AEM.The problem is when I submit the login button on the component the siteminder forwards request to https://test1-myuhc.uhc.com/bin/uhc/myuhcauthenticationhandler which gives a 404 error. When I set the target to some real page that exists under /content it works without any issue. What can I do to work this out.

Here is the code :

```
package com.myuhc.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.sling.SlingServlet;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet;
import org.apache.sling.settings.SlingSettingsService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

// TODO: Auto-generated Javadoc
/**
 * The Class LoginAuthenticationHandlerServlet.
 */
/*@SlingServlet(
        paths={"/bin/myuhc/authenticationhandler"},
        methods = {"POST","GET"},
        metatype=true
        )*/
@Component(immediate = true, metatype = true)
@Service
@Properties({
        @Property(name = "sling.servlet.paths", value = "/bin/uhc/myuhcauthenticationhandler"),
        @Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = {"GET","POST"}) })
public class LoginAuthenticationHandlerServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** The Constant log. */
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginAuthenticationHandlerServlet.class);

    @Reference
    private SlingSettingsService settingsService;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet#doPost(org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest, org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse)
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request,SlingHttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            if (settingsService.getRunModes().contains("publish")) {
                //response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                response.setContentType("text/plain");
                Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
                String cookieValue = null;
                String uhcRole = null;
                String uhcaccountstatus = null;
                String url = null;
                String LOGIN_PAGE = "/content/myuhc/en/myuhc-login-page.html";
                String HOME_PAGE = "/content/myuhc/en/myuhc-home-page.html";
                //getting headers
                uhcRole = request.getHeader("uhcRole");
                uhcaccountstatus = request.getHeader("uhcaccountstatus");
                //getting SMRESPONSECODE cookie set by Siteminder
                if (cookies !=null) {
                    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                        if(cookie.getName().equals("SMRESPONSECODE")) {
                            cookieValue = cookie.getValue();
                        }
                        // TODO:: Needs to be validated
                        cookie.setMaxAge(-1);
                    }
                    //Setting the URL by checking the different conditions
                    if (cookieValue !=null) {
                        if (cookieValue.equals("1")) {
                            request.setAttribute("message", "Member not found");
                            url = LOGIN_PAGE;
                        }
                        else if(cookieValue.equals("2")) {
                            request.setAttribute("message", "Wrong password. Please try again.");
                            url = LOGIN_PAGE;
                        }
                        else if((uhcaccountstatus!=null) && !uhcaccountstatus.equals("A") && cookieValue.equals("3")) {
                            request.setAttribute("message", "Member not found");
                            url = LOGIN_PAGE;
                        }
                        else if((uhcaccountstatus!=null) && (uhcRole!=null) && !uhcRole.equals("employer") && uhcaccountstatus.equals("A") && cookieValue.equals("0")) {
                            url = HOME_PAGE;
                        }
                        else if((uhcRole!=null) && uhcRole.equals("employer") && cookieValue.equals("4")) {
                            url = HOME_PAGE;
                        }
                        else if (cookieValue.equals("5") || cookieValue.equals("6")) {
                            request.setAttribute("message", "Member not found or Wrong password");
                            url = LOGIN_PAGE;
                        }

                    }else {
                        log.info("No Cookies found!");
                    }
                }
                //Forwarding the request to the url set above
                request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
            }
        }
        catch (ServletException e) {
            log.info("Inside ServletException -->"+e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            log.info("Inside IOException -->"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet#doGet(org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest, org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse)
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request,SlingHttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            if (settingsService.getRunModes().contains("publish")) {
                //response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                response.setContentType("text/plain");
                Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
                String cookieValue = null;
                String uhcRole = null;
                String uhcaccountstatus = null;
                String url = null;
                String LOGIN_PAGE = "/content/myuhc/en/myuhc-login-page.html";
                String HOME_PAGE = "/content/myuhc/en/myuhc-home-page.html";
                //getting headers
                uhcRole = request.getHeader("uhcRole");
                uhcaccountstatus = request.getHeader("uhcaccountstatus");
                //getting SMRESPONSECODE cookie set by Siteminder
                if (cookies !=null) {
                    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                        if(cookie.getName().equals("SMRESPONSECODE")) {
                            cookieValue = cookie.getValue();
                        }
                        // TODO:: Needs to be validated
                        cookie.setMaxAge(-1);
                    }
                    //Setting the URL by checking the different conditions
                    if (cookieValue !=null) {
                        if (cookieValue.equals("1")) {
                            request.setAttribute("message", "Member not found");
                            url = LOGIN_PAGE;
                        }
                        else if(cookieValue.equals("2")) {
                            request.setAttribute("message", "Wrong password. Please try again.");
                            url = LOGIN_PAGE;
                        }
                        else if((uhcaccountstatus!=null) && !uhcaccountstatus.equals("A") && cookieValue.equals("3")) {
                            request.setAttribute("message", "Member not found");
                            url = LOGIN_PAGE;
                        }
                        else if((uhcaccountstatus!=null) && (uhcRole!=null) && !uhcRole.equals("employer") && uhcaccountstatus.equals("A") && cookieValue.equals("0")) {
                            url = HOME_PAGE;
                        }
                        else if((uhcRole!=null) && uhcRole.equals("employer") && cookieValue.equals("4")) {
                            url = HOME_PAGE;
                        }
                        else if (cookieValue.equals("5") || cookieValue.equals("6")) {
                            request.setAttribute("message", "Member not found or Wrong password");
                            url = LOGIN_PAGE;
                        }

                    }else {
                        log.info("No Cookies found!");
                    }
                }
                //Forwarding the request to the url set above
                request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
            }
        }
        catch (ServletException e) {
            log.info("Inside ServletException -->"+e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            log.info("Inside IOException -->"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the form

```
<form id="site-login" method="post" action="https://test1-myuhc.uhc.com/siteminderagent/forms/login-aa.fcc">
                    <fieldset class="borderless">
                        <legend class="hide-text">
                           ${xss:encodeForHTML(xssAPI, loginTitle)}
                        </legend>
                        <div>
                            <label for="username" class="micro strong label--inline">${xss:encodeForHTML(xssAPI, usrnamelbl)}</label>
                            <input type="text" id="username" name="USER" class="input--login" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="password" class="micro strong label--inline">${xss:encodeForHTML(xssAPI, pswrdlbl)}</label>
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="PASSWORD" class="input--login" />
                        </div>
                        <button class="button--blue milli float-right">${xss:encodeForHTML(xssAPI, btnlbl)}</button>

                    </fieldset>
                    <input type="hidden" name="IDToken0" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="SMENC" value="ISO-8859-1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="SMLOCALE" value="en-us">
                    <input type="hidden" name="target" value="/bin/uhc/myuhcauthenticationhandler">
                    <input type="hidden" name="theme" value="myuhc">
                </form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try checking if the URL is resolved through your Resource Resolver(`/system/console/jcrresolver`) and the servlet is configured to respond to the corresponding request methods (GET or POST based on how you are requesting it). Are you sure there are no extensions specified for the servlet and the component is in activate state in felix?

Comment: Yeah I checked the URL is resolving. It is resolving to the servlet. I have also implemented both doGet and doPost and added @Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = {"GET","POST"}) }) at the top of the classes. The bundle is active and I am not sure if I should use extension. Does it makes any difference ?

Comment: It would be difficult to comment without looking at the code. Can you add the code sample, at least the skeleton of your class along with all the annotations and configurations, so that others can check.

Comment: This code should work. However there are 2 things you can check. 1. Since you are accessing through domain, check if your servlet is allowed in the dispatcher filters. 2. CQ5 generally expects a referrer header for POST requests. So check if the appropriate headers are received. Also, in case redirect is from an external domain, then allow it in the Apache Sling Referrer Filter available at `/system/console/configMgr`

Comment: What confuses me a bit is the redundant definitions. It is enough to use the SlingServlet and Component annotations, you don't need the Service and Properties as they are already covered with SlingServlet. The next thing is the visibility of the methods, shouldn't they be public instead of protected? And last but not least, code duplication is bad, just call doPost from within doGet or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got what you mean by dispatcher filters. BTW, can you suggest exactly what entry should I make in the dispatcher to make it work. Also, I am not sure what do you mean by referrer header. Could you please advise how do I allow the external domain in Apache Slng Referrer Filter at configMgr. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Give name to your servlet as below or any unique [search in workspace this name should be unique]

```
@SlingServlet(
        paths={"/bin/myuhc/authenticationhandler"},
        methods = {"POST","GET"},
        metatype=true,
        name = "authentication handler servlet" // give name in servlet and build the project
        )
```

After clean installing the snapshot jar again

Go to localhost:/system/console/components (You can directly go in felix console (system/console/bundles) -> OSGI -> components)

ctrl+f search the name (which is "authentication handler servlet" in our example)
There you'll find the path of the servlet. Check for the following

```
Implementation Class = LoginAuthenticationHandlerServlet 
sling.servlet.paths = [/bin/myuhc/authenticationhandler]
```

The implementing class and path should match with your servlet. If the path is not matching that means the servlet url that is being hit belongs to someother servlet that may even doesn't exist. Also, double check the name should be unique in workspace.

Hope that helps.